# Setting Up PHP and MySQL Development Environment

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website with PHP and using MySQL as the database, so I need help setting up the development environment. I want to execute and test the PHP scripts locally, with all the local database connections and all the operations possible on database by PHP scripts.

I'm on Windows and I've installed MySQL and Eclipse IDE for PHP, so how do I connect these two applications, so that the scripts related to database can directly execute queries on this MySQL installation? Also the Eclipse IDE isn't able to execute the scripts on localhost, it returns this error "The webpage cannot be found".

So how can this be solved and connections be made to MySQL?

Comment: I've found [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) very easy to use so you may want to check that out. Also, please learn how to format your text here on SO

Comment: Yes, XAMPP and you'll find Aptana is a useful Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Yes please to what @General_Twyckenham said, we love paragraphs here!

Comment: Database connections are generally made from code you write, although you can do so inside the `mysql` client and other client apps too.

Comment: so by just by running this code here: http://pastebin.com/JLShvqHH, will make the connection without doing any further procedure

Comment: You'll need to create a database account first. If you have installed XAMPP then you will already have a root password, use that to create a non-root user (search for "mysql create user" if you need to know how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to connect your website to the database? What server are you using? WAMP or XAMPP? You need to first install the server. You can install wamp from here http://www.wampserver.com/en/.

This would be your starting point.

Comment: Does Eclipse IDE for PHP, require a WAMP/ Xampp installation to run scripts in localhost

Comment: No IDE doesn't need a webserver , but for you to be able to connect your PHP scripts with your database and check it in your local environment you need to have some kind of web server.